# How can I assign a value of a variable when an event happens?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

In Tkinter, how can I assign a value of a variable when an event happens?

```
from Tkinter import *

def on_Click(event):
    print(event.x, event.y)
    return 'hello world !'

root = Tk()
root.bind("<Button-1>", on_Click)
myVariable = on_Click()
# rest of the program
root.mainloop()
```

How can I assign the value of `myVariable` to the value of `on_Click()` when `on_Click`is triggered (by clicking on the widget)?

The rest of the program would be executed only when a value has successfully been assigned to `myVariable`. Blocking the program while no click has been recorded.

Answer (score 0):

Thing is the whole program runs when you start the script, everything that is not in a function gets loaded at the start to build the UI.... and the real work starts when a function is loaded, such as the one you wrote (`on_Click`).

What you need to do is reference the `myVariable` inside the function, and then send the variable to another function that will be the rest of your program.

```
from Tkinter import *

variable = None

def on_Click(event):
    print(event.x, event.y)
    variable = 'hello world !'
    main(variable)

root = Tk()
root.bind("<Button-1>", on_Click)

def main(x):
# rest of the program

root.mainloop()
```

This is the way I got it to work, don't forget that every time you are going to click on the widget the program will be loaded again.